# How do I run 1 of 3 javascript functions randomly?

Tags: javascript, cookies, random

I want to show a random image to a page visitor, then only show that same image to the same visitor until the cookie expires.

Everything works properly but I'm stuck on the initialization.

Basically, if there is no cookie set, I need to run 1 of 3 functions randomly.
How would I go about choosing the one of 3 functions at random and running it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
var cookie = readCookie("boatColor");
if (!cookie) {
  console.log('Run one of 3 Functions Randomly');
  } else if (cookie == "boatRed") {
    showRedBoat();
  } else if (cookie == "boatWhite") {
    showWhiteBoat();
  } else if (cookie == "boatBlue") {
    showBlueBoat();
  }
}); 


function showRedBoat() {
    var newSrc = ""; 
      var myText = "";
    newSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500458/copeland_boat_red.jpg"; 
        myText = "<h3>You've got the Red Boat!</h3>";
    theImage.src = newSrc; 
    theDesc.innerHTML = myText;
    createCookie("boatColor", 'boatRed', 0.00034722222);
}

function showWhiteBoat() {
    var newSrc = ""; 
      var myText = "";
    newSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500458/copeland_boat_white.jpg"; 
        myText = "<h3>You've got the White Boat!</h3>";
    theImage.src = newSrc; 
    theDesc.innerHTML = myText;
    createCookie("boatColor", 'boatWhite', 0.00034722222);
}

function showBlueBoat() {
    var newSrc = ""; 
      var myText = "";
    newSrc = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500458/copeland_boat_blue.jpg"; 
        myText = "<h3>You've got the Blue Boat!</h3>";
    theImage.src = newSrc; 
    theDesc.innerHTML = myText;
    createCookie("boatColor", 'boatBlue', 0.00034722222);
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
```

}

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/nolaandy/pen/awgoQM

Comment: Set an expiration date for tommorow on the cookies.

Comment: If your question is how to choose randomly 1 out of 3 functions and run it, why is any of the other code relevant (which you claim works as it should)? It does not seem like the cookie handling is relevant to the question. Can you reduce the code to the part you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to generate a random number if there is no cookie set, then run one of three functions based on that number:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  var cookie = readCookie("boatColor");

  if (!cookie) {
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  var randomNumber = getRandomInt(0,2);

  if (randomNumber == 0) {
    showRedBoat();
    } else if (randomNumber == 1) {
  showWhiteBoat();
  } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
  showBlueBoat();
  }
      } else if (cookie == "boatRed") {
        showRedBoat();
      } else if (cookie == "boatWhite") {
        showWhiteBoat();
      } else if (cookie == "boatBlue") {
        showBlueBoat();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `new Date().getTime() % 3` to get a pseudo random number between 0 and 2. Then just use a switch statement to call one function or another.